# How to receive data from the Wii Remote in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, wiimote

I'm trying to write a Cocoa application which allows me to see what buttons I'm pressing on my Wii Remote. I also want to be able to receive Nunchuck-data and set the LEDs. Does anyone know where I can start?

Oh, yes I did some [searches](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=cocoa+wiimote), but I couldn't find anything useful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an [open-source project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/darwiin-remote/) working on Wiimote support in OS X. They have a Cocoa-based library called WiRemoteFramework.

Answer (score 2):

On [episode 1](http://www.pixelcorps.tv/macbreak_dev001) of MacBreak Dev, they show how to read from the Wii Remote and use it to drive a Quartz Composer composition.  They use the [WiiMote Control](http://kineme.net/WiiMoteControlPatch20080111publicbeta) patch for Quartz Composer from [Kineme](http://kineme.net/).  It sounds like that patch is based on the darwiin-remote project that Chuck links to in his answer.

This might let you do rapid prototyping of your application design, and you could even incorporate a working Quartz Composer composition into your Cocoa application when done.